# MongoDB Atlas returns empty array on Heroku, works fine locally

Tags: node.js, mongodb, heroku, mongoose

Im running a simple REST API in Heroku (https://rest-api-moviedemo.herokuapp.com/leffat). Locally it works fine and fetches a bunch of movie data from MongoDB Atlas.

When moved to Heroku, Im getting an empty array.[]  No errors in logs.

Code is fairly straightforward:

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
const MongoClient = require("mongodb").MongoClient;
// USING CONFIG_VARS TO HOLD DB CREDENTIALS 
const uri = process.env.DB_URI;
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;
 
 

mongoose.connect(uri, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true });


const Movie = mongoose.model(
  "Movie",
  {
    title: String,
    year: Number,
    poster: String,
  },
  "movies" 
);


app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.send("This is a sample REST API.");
});

var query = {title: /indiana jones/i };
app.get("/leffat", async (req, res) => {
 await Movie.find(query, function (err, results) {
   if (err) res.send(err);
    console.log("Results: " + results);
    res.json(results);
  });
});

app.listen(PORT, function () {
  console.log("Listening");
});
```

What might be wrong?

br, Mika

Comment: Have you included your ``.ENV`` File on heroku ?

Comment: Im reading config vars from Heroku. Connection seems to work but results to an empty array.

Comment: @mika .. how did you get this error fixed..? It seems like the url is getting the data .. how did you get this working?