# Heroku Connecting to MongoDB but HTTP Requests Not Working

Tags: node.js, mongodb, heroku

I'm confident I'm facing the same error as this: [MongoDB Atlas returns empty array on Heroku, works fine locally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66905211/mongodb-atlas-returns-empty-array-on-heroku-works-fine-locally). I'm sure my config env file is ok.

My app's backend on heroku seems to connect to the mongodb server, i.e  the following code block successfully prints DB connection success.

```
  .connect(`${process.env.DATABASE}`, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useCreateIndex: true,
    useFindAndModify: false,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
  })
  .then(() => {
    console.log("DB Connection Success");
  });
```

However, whenever I do a normal, simple get request, it always can't find the data. I.e the route is being found, but the catch block in my function is being reached. i.e

```
exports.getSingleDish = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const dish = await Dish.findById({ _id: req.params.id });
    console.log(dish, req.params.id)
    if (!dish) {
      console.log("No dish with this id exists");
    }
    res.status(200).json({
      status: "success",
      json: {
        data: dish,
      },
    });
  } catch (err) {
    console.log("There was an error getting the dish")
  }
};
```

When this function is called via my API, dish is null. But when I do the same request with localhost instead of my heroku app, the dish is not null. SO on heroku or the deployed backend I get the message "There was an error creating the dish", as opposed to the actual returning of the dish occurring locally.

I have whitelisted all IPs for atlas. I am also confident the connection string is correct. The one in the heroku environment variables is the same as the one I'm using locally, and everything is working locally. I also copied the same mongodb URI into mongoDB compass and was able to retrieve my database and all its data.

This honestly seems like magic to me. Everything was working fine a month back. I've also made sure the nom and node versions on the package.json are the same as that locally that I'm using.

Any advice as to how to debug this?